# Jquery AJAX post request doesn't receive response on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

I send off a jquery post request to my own PHP script. The simplified code is below:

```
var dataString = "email="+$("#email").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val();

$.post("scripts/login.php", dataString, function(result){
     alert(result);
});
```

On desktop (both google chrome and internet explorer) the script works fine and login happens almost instantaneously.

However on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S7) the request never completes on either the stock browser or chrome for android, and if I implement a `.fail()` function it will triger after a few seconds.

By adding some logging into my PHP I fould out the script receives the request and sends the response correctly, but it seems my phone is not picking up the result.

The login page worked fine on my phone only several hours ago and my colleague who has a sony xperia using chrome for android can use the login script fine as well.

What could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Could you please try keep your code inside 
$(document).ready()
{ //your code });